# FCM: Cannot click notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

I'm using the recently release [FCM messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) support for push notifications on the chrome. When my app is in the background, I get the notification but nothing happens when I click the notification. How to I specify the URL which should open when the user clicks the notification? (I understand how its done using the pure service worker concept using the notificationclick event, I want to know how to do that using [FCM messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).)

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  var data = payload || {};
  var shinyData = decoder.run(data);

  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', shinyData);

  return self.registration.showNotification(shinyData.title, {
    body: shinyData.body,
    icon: shinyData.icon
  })
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15):

`click_action` is not one of the possible parameters of the [showNotification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) function.

To handle the click on the notification, define a [notificationclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/notificationclick) event handler.

For example:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(YOUR_URL_HERE));
});
```

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. I understand how to do that using the notificationClick event, but I dont know how to do that using the firebase messaging library. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm struggling with this response... what does 'self' refer to in this context? Is it the notification, the service worker registration or some other object entirely?

Comment: To answer my previous comment, the `self.addEventListener` should go in the script you provide when registering the service worker. The reason it wasn't working for me was because my script was being cached. I needed to unregister my service worker, ensure the script was no longer cached and then re-register the service worker.

Answer (score 10):

Marco's answer is correct.

The Firebase Messaging Library is a wrapper on top of the Web Push API.

The `notification: { click_action: 'https://...' }` payload will show a notification and handle the click for you. To achieve the same with data payload you should implement the `notificationclick` event listener (Like Marco suggested).

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();

  ... Do your stuff here.
});
```

You can also do the same with the `notificationclose` event:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclose', function(event) {
  ... Do your stuff here.
});
```