# Notification click on Service Worker

Tags: notifications, service-worker

I develop a notification using Service Worker because I need to show the notification on desktop and mobile browsers, but I don't know how to handle the notification click event.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');

        Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
            if (Notification.permission !== result) {
                Notification.permission = result;
            }
          if (result === 'granted') {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
                    var fecha = Date.now("Y-m-d");

                    registration.showNotification("Usted ha recibido una solicitud web! ", {
                        tag: 'soManyNotification',
                        body: 'Nombre: juanito \nMonto: $300 USD \nDestino: Miami',
                        icon: 'icon.png',
                        timestamp: fecha
                    });
            });
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The sw.js registered is an empty file.

Kind regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM: Cannot click notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201719/fcm-cannot-click-notification)

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40202565/5769903 applies here as well.

Comment: Dear Marco, I watch the event listener, but in what part of the code I need to put the event handler? Where can I find a fiddle of your solution? (I'm sorry if my english is bad, but I'm not an English native speaker)

Comment: You can put it at the top-level of your service worker script.

Comment: Hi Marco, the code works fine but only in Google Chrome. How can I add the notification click handler to work on Mozilla Firefox or another browser?

Comment: Can you try `event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(YOUR_URL_HERE));` instead of `return self.clients.openWindow(YOUR_URL_HERE);`?

Comment: Here is also a cross browser demo: https://serviceworke.rs/push-clients_service-worker_doc.html