# Firebase FCM fcm_options.link doesn't work

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using multicast to send the message to multiple users like this:

```
        let webAppMessage = {
          priority:'high',
          notification:{title: titleNotif , body: `${name}: ${message}`, image: 'https://i.imgur.com/L6plOZO.png'},
          tokens: webTokens,
          webpush: {
            fcm_options: {
              link: "https://dummy.com" 
            }
          }
        admin.messaging().sendMulticast(webAppMessage)
```

However, clicking on the notification doesn't direct to the link.
I'm using firebase 8.6.3. I checked the other posts, but they don't resolve my issue. Is this because I'm using multicast to send the message? I can't find anything on the documentation about that.

Answer (score 1):

This post solved it for me:
[Firebase push notifications click does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686203/firebase-push-notifications-click-does-not-work/67862849#67862849)
Just use relative links... unlike what their documentation claims